# Why is backtracking unable to generate all possible combinations?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array, backtracking

I have a 2D array of the form `{{"x"},{"a","b","c"},{"1","2","3"}}`.

I want to generate all the following combinations :

```
xa1
xa2
xa3
xb1
xb2
xb3
xc1
xc2
xc3
```

I have written the following recursive code to generate the combinations :

```
String dim[][] ={{"x"},{"a","b","c"},{"1","2","3"}};
void fun(int i,int j,String []metric)
{


    if(i>=dim.length)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
            System.out.print(metric[k]);    
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }

    if(j>=dim[i].length)
            return;
        metric[i] = dim[i][j];
    fun(i+1,j,metric);

    fun(i,j+1,metric);



}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    String metric[] = new String[20];
    Ideone b = new Ideone();
    b.fun(0,0,metric);
}
```

And I get the following incomplete output:

```
xa1
xa2
xa3
xb2
xb3
xc3
```

I am unable to generate all the combination as mentioned and I cannot figure out which case I'm missing/error in my logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you replace

```
fun(i+1,j,metric);
```

with

```
fun(i+1,0,metric);
```

Comment: Because you should iterate over all elements of the next array, not just the ones which bigger than current `j` value.